# How to correctly substitute a part of a matching pattern in R?

Tags: regex, r, substitution

A simple example.

Original char vector:

```
> sats
[1] "G 5" "G 7" "G 9" "G10" "G13" "G16" "G19" "G20" "G27" "G28" "G30"
```

Then gsub:

```
sats=gsub("G ","G0",sats)
> sats
[1] "G05" "G07" "G09" "G10" "G13" "G16" "G19" "G20" "G27" "G28" "G30"
```

The matching pattern is "G ". Is there a way for me to change only the second character that is a space, not by overwriting the entire matched piece. Or for example to insert a character between the chars in the matched piece. What I'm trying to do is to figure out how the regexps tools work rather than solving a specific problem. Thanks.

Comment: Try `sub('(?<=G)\\s', '0', sats, perl=TRUE)`

Comment: @akrun Kiss, `sub("\\s", '0', stats)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you are asking about how to use submatches.

Substituting a part of a patten can be done by *capturing what you need to keep and only match what you want to replace*.

See [IDEONE demo](http://ideone.com/4bGW3h):

```
sats <- c("G 5","G 7","G 9","G10","G13","G16","G19","G20","G27","G28","G30")
gsub('([[:alpha:]]+) ', '\\10', sats)
##  [1] "G05" "G07" "G09" "G10" "G13" "G16" "G19" "G20" "G27" "G28" "G30"
```

Here, `([[:alpha:]]+)` is a capturing group (a paire of unescaped parentheses) that is stored in a buffer #1, and we can call it in the replacement pattern with a `\1` backreference. (Note that `(G)`  is a very weird example, that is why I suggested a POSIX character class `[[:alpha:]]` that matches lower- and uppercase letters only and added a `+` that matches one or more occurrences.)

Comment: Glad it worked for you. Please also consider upvoting if my answer proved helpful to you.